# How to check whether a directory with a specific name exists in c#?

Tags: c#

How do I check whether a folder named `xyz` exist in a given path(recursively) and if it exits then get its full path so that I can copy some files from it?
Will something like below work or am I missing something?

```
if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(textBox1.Text, "xyz"))
{
    string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(root, directoryName, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

where root is the path to start in and directoryName is the specific name you're looking for. You can use `.Any()` to check if it exists and `.First()` to get the first.

**edited after pinkfloydx33 comment**

Yeah, EnumerateDirectories would be better. Sorry, I'm stuck in .net 3.5 mode at the moment :D so you'd be looking for this:

```
Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root, directoryName, SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();
```

and checking for null.

Comment: It depends on what you're looking for. Arrays are type-castable to IEnumerable so you can use Directory.GetDirectories(root, directoryName, SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault() to get null or the first item in the list. I would expect that you'd need the list though, but I suppose it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: EnumerateDirectories would be preferable- and it returns an enumerable. GetDirectories will return all results at once which means if there were thousands of matches you gets a large array the could potentially take a lot of time as well. EnumerateDirectories on the other hand will stop at the first match if you were using Any/First/FirstOrDefault and you can always call ToArray/ToList if needed. Probably not a big deal here, but this exact thing has bitten me in a production app and ever since I never use GetDirectories/GetFiles

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Can you show it with some code, I'm getting a bit confused...